# Error trying to compile default CXF project with Maven

Tags: maven, cxf, archetypes

I am trying to use the archetype: org.apache.cxf.archetype:cxf-jaxws-javafirst
and do a Maven compile. Am getting this error: I tried with different versions of JDK, but couldn't succeed. Pls help.

```
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to D:\myApp\ProcessOrder\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: error reading D:\Documents and Settings\User1\.m2\repository\x
ml-resolver\xml-resolver\1.2\xml-resolver-1.2.jar; cannot read zip file entry
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.859s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Nov 26 09:24:24 IST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/13M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
3.2:compile (default-compile) on project ProcessOrder: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: error reading D:\Documents and Settings\User1\.m2\repository\x
ml-resolver\xml-resolver\1.2\xml-resolver-1.2.jar; cannot read zip file entry
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on
 project ProcessOrder: Compilation failure
error: error reading D:\Documents and Settings\User1\.m2\repository\xml-resol
ver\xml-resolver\1.2\xml-resolver-1.2.jar; cannot read zip file entry

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:213)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error: error reading D:\Documents and
>   Settings\User1.m2\repository\xml-resol
>   ver\xml-resolver\1.2\xml-resolver-1.2.jar; cannot read zip file entry

Perhaps you should delete this jar or better still the folder holding the jar and try again.  It looks like the jar is corrupt.

Comment: Works for me with maven-3.0.3 on Windows 7 32-bit. Chose `2.5.0` version of archetype `org.apache.cxf.archetype:cxf-jaxws-javafirst`. Maybe you can verify if the size of `xml-resolver-1.2.jar` is 83KB as it is on my system.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I checked, I had a larger size jar. Recompiled, all's looking good now.